# jQuery Mobile: How do you change an Input (type="submit") Icon after the page has been displayed?

Tags: jquery-mobile, input

I'm having some problems dynamically changing input icons for my submit button, after the page has been created and displayed.

For anchors I can get the icon image to change using .buttonMarkup(). For example:

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor" name="myAnchor" value="heart" data-ajax="false"
class="ui-btn ui-icon-heart ui-btn-icon-bottom ui-shadow ui-corner-all"
data-iconpos="center" role="button">Tap to Start</a>
```

and the following changes the icon from a heart to moon-o

```
$('#myAnchor').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'moon-o' });
```

For an Input of type Submit, I usually have to use the data-* attributes to define the icon, position, etc. The buttonMarkup() method doesn't seem to work.

```
<input type="submit" id="myInputSubmit" value="Submit" 
class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-moon-o ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inline" 
data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-corners="true" 
data-shadow="true" role="button">
```

and jQuery

```
$('#myInputSubmit').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'moon-o' });
```

Anyone know how to alter this Input button after the page create/display has already been managed by jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an input dom element, jQM creates a button widget: http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/

To change the icon of a button widget, use the icon option:
http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/#option-icon

```
$("#myInputSubmit").button( "option", "icon", "moon-o" );
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/j9723ns5/)**